# Can't download Docusign document when envelope name has quotes

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign API (via the ruby docusign_rest gem) and repro'd this using Postman.

I have an envelope whose name has quotes in it. When I tried to download the signed PDF, I get an error message:

[https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/documents/1](https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/envelopes/%7Benvelope_id%7D/documents/1)

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
  "message": "The format of value 'file; filename=\"My filename (\"MF\") has quotes.pdf\"; documentid=\"1\"' is invalid."
}
```

When I list the documents, it shows the name of the envelope having quotes.

[https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account_id}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/documents](https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D/envelopes/%7Benvelope_id%7D/documents)

```
{
  "envelopeId": "{envelope_id}",
  "envelopeDocuments": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "My filename (\"MF\") has quotes.pdf",
      "type": "content",
      "uri": "/envelopes/{envelop_id}/documents/1",
etc...
    }
}
```

I can change my code to prevent quotes for new documents, but I have existing signed documents that I can't download. How can I download them? Or fix them?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to properly escape the quotes in your json.

The only way to know what is really happening is to see the api logs.

**Added**

To see the api logs, you have two choices:

1. See the [instructions](https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging)
2. Use the [API Logging Feature of the new (still beta) Recipe tool](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python). has a more convenient interface to the API Logger.

Comment: I can definitely adjust how I send the names of the envelopes. But that's only helpful for future documents. Is there any way to salvage the existing documents that have already been signed? You mention the API logs, is that something that Docusign can help me with?

Answer (score 1):

Using the current docusign_rest release (v0.3.1) I was able to create an envelope with a quote in the document's filename and then download that document:

```
client = DocusignRest::Client.new
res = client.create_envelope_from_document(email: {subject: "test email subject",body: "this is the email body and it's large!"}, signers: [{embedded: true, name: 'Joe Dimaggio', email: 'joe.dimaggio@example.org', role_name: 'Issuer',sign_here_tabs: [{anchor_string: 'sign here',anchor_x_offset: '-30',anchor_y_offset: '35'}]},], files: [{path: '/Users/tomcopeland/github.com/docusign_rest/test".pdf', name: 'test".pdf'},],status: 'sent')
client.get_document_from_envelope(envelope_id: res['envelopeId'], document_id: "1", local_save_path: "/tmp/foobar.pdf")
client.get_documents_from_envelope(envelope_id: res['envelopeId'])["envelopeDocuments"].map {|d| d["name"] }
=> ["test\".pdf", "Summary"]
```

Also, this latest release [supports call logging](https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest/commit/38817310853b79a90da712fc1d00db4798243150) so, if needed, you can extract logs client-side.